# Pairing records in table using column and then finding Children records? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I am trying to pair two or more records in a grandparent table so that I can then find its grand children records using one grandchild to start from.

Each Product_Maintenance record has a Product **Parent** record, each Product record has is part of a Product_Group **Grandparent** record.

As illustrated.[image]

So my query will start off with a newly created grandchild (Product_Maintenace) record that was made today, and will traverse up the hierarchy to the Granparent record. Then it will find all other Grand children and then join them to the result set.

This is my query so far, but the problem is it seems to just duplicate the results of one grandchild record and does not join on the others, I think this is because my WHERE clause filters them out because they do not have a created date of today.

```
    SELECT product_id, created_date, maintenance_level 
FROM Maintenance maint
    --Traversing Up
    JOIN Products prods
      ON maint.product_id = prods.product_id
    JOIN Groups grps
      ON prods.parent_row_id = grps.row_id
    --Find the linking of Groups
    JOIN Groups link
      ON grps.product_group_id = link.product_group_id
    --Traversing down
    --Now that all linked records are found find all children of those linked grandparents
    JOIN Products prods
      ON prods.par_row_id = link.row_id
    JOIN Maintenance maint
      ON maint.product_id = prods.product_id
WHERE 
    CREATED_DATE = sysdate
```

Would this be where an Nested select statement would come in useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straight-forward solution would be to have the WHERE clause include the list of relevant Product_Group_IDs.

```
SELECT maint.product_id, maint.created_date, maint.maintenance_level 
FROM Maintenance maint
JOIN Products prods ON maint.product_id = prods.product_id
JOIN Groups grps ON prods.parent_row_id = grps.row_id
WHERE grps.Product_Group_ID IN
(   SELECT grps.Product_Group_ID
    FROM Maintenance maint
    JOIN Products prods ON maint.product_id = prods.product_id
    JOIN Groups grps ON prods.parent_row_id = grps.row_id
    WHERE maint.Created_Date = sysdate
)
```

Or alternatively, LEFT JOIN your way up and back down the chain:

```
SELECT maint2.product_id, maint2.created_date, maint2.maintenance_level 
FROM Maintenance maint1
LEFT JOIN Products prods1 ON maint1.product_id = prods1.product_id
LEFT JOIN Groups grps1 ON prods1.parent_row_id = grps1.row_id
LEFT JOIN Groups grps2 ON grps1.product_group_id = grps2.product_group_id
LEFT JOIN Products prods2 ON prods2.par_row_id = grps2.row_id
LEFT JOIN Maintenance maint2 ON maint2.product_id = prods2.product_id
WHERE maint1.CREATED_DATE = sysdate
```

Comment: Interesting, I get no results with the first query.